# BYTE BCD to ASCII conversion optimization

Tags: c, string, ascii, bcd

I've written a function in c that converts a byte (unsigned char) BCD string into ASCII.  Please have look at the code and advice some improvements.

Is there any other efficient way that can convert BYTE BCD to ASCII.

```
BYTE_BCD_to_ASC(BYTE *SrcString, char *DesString)
{

        switch (((BCD *)SrcString)->l)
        {
            case 10:/*A*/
            case 11:/*B*/
            case 12:/*C*/
            case 13:/*D*/
            case 14:/*E*/
            case 15:/*F*/
                *DesString = (char)(((BCD *)SrcString)->l + '0' + 7);
                break;
            default:
                *DesString = (char)(((BCD *)SrcString)->l + '0');
                break;
        }

        switch (((BCD *)SrcString)->h)
        {
            case 10:
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
                *(DesString + 1) = (char)(((BCD *)SrcString)->h + '0' + 7);
                break;
            default:
                *(DesString + 1) = (char)(((BCD *)SrcString)->h + '0');
                break;
        }
    *(DesString + 2) = '\0';
}
```

thanks

Fakhar

Answer (score 5):

I think I'd do something like this:

```
void BCD2ASC(unsigned char src, char *dest) { 
    static const char outputs[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    *dest++ = outputs[src>>4];
    *dest++ = outputs[src&0xf];
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Comment: In my understanding, BCD only contains digits from 0 to 9.  So no need for A - F.

Comment: @Thomas: there shouldn't be, but his code took that possibility into account, so I did too. In reality, I seem to recall some types of BCD using those codes for decimal points and rough equivalents of NaN and Infinity, but I don't recall any details. In any case, using a table lookup makes it trivial to treat those any way you prefer.

Comment: You could also make the `outputs` array `const`... or even just use `#define outputs "0123456789ABCDEF"` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void BCD_To_ASCII(unsigned char bcd_value, char * p_ascii_text)
{
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // BCD contains digits 0 .. 9 in the binary nibbles
  //--------------------------------------------------
  *p_ascii_text++ = (bcd_value >> 4)  + '0';
  *p_ascii_text++ = (bcd_value & 0x0f) + '0';
  *p_ascii_text = '\0';
  return;
}
```

Comment: @Jerry @Thomas, Thank you for your response, I believe now I'll be able to improve my code....

Comment: please also help me how can I incorporate the conversion of Reverse-BCD in the routine.

Comment: @Fakhar:  Please define "Reverse-BCD".

Comment: @Thomas, actually there are two structures defined in the header file as follows 
<code>
#ifdef __IBM__ #pragma option align=packed typedef struct { unsigned l : 4; unsigned h : 4; } BCD; typedef struct { unsigned h : 4; unsigned l : 4; } BCD_REVERSE; #pragma option align=reset
</code> 
now I think that any BCD number can be represented in two formats, BCD and REVERSE-BCD, may be the Reverse shall be with swapped nibbles, however there are systems sending time in this format. Now, I need to know how your code shall be modified to take care of this REVERSE option.

Comment: @Thomas, another define is as follows <code> #elif defined(__COMPAQ__) typedef struct { unsigned char h : 4; unsigned char l : 4; } BCD; typedef struct { unsigned char l : 4; unsigned char h : 4; } BCD_REVERSE; #endif </code>

Comment: @Fakhar:  The ASCII digits are calculated as: `high = (bcd_value >> 4) + '0';` and `low = (bcd_value & 0x0f) + '0';`.  To convert your `BCD` and `BCD_REVERSE`, just add '0' to ".l" for the low value and to ".h" for the high value.

Comment: @Thomas, @R.. If you know the output is ASCII, then `+ '0'` may be the *wrong* thing to use, an implementation is not required to map `'0'` to the ASCII value representing the zero character, but if you *need* ASCII then you should use `+ 0x30` directly.

Answer (score 1):

finally I have implemented the routine as follows

```
static const char s_szHexAscNo[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

void BYTE_BCD_to_ASC(BYTE *SrcString, char DesString[3], int BCDflag)
{
    assert(SrcString != NULL);
    assert(DesString != NULL);

    if ( BCDFlag_Normal == BCDflag)
    {
        *DesString++ = (char) s_szHexAscNo[((BCD *)SrcString)->l];
        *DesString++ = (char) s_szHexAscNo[((BCD *)SrcString)->h];
    }

    if (BCDFlag_Reverse == BCDflag)
    {
        *DesString++ = (char) s_szHexAscNo[((BCD_REVERSE *)SrcString)->l];
        *DesString++ = (char) s_szHexAscNo[((BCD_REVERSE *)SrcString)->h];
    }
    *DesString = '\0';
}

/* BCD and BCD_REVERSE  are defined as */

typedef struct
{
unsigned char    l : 4;
unsigned char    h : 4;
} BCD;

typedef struct
{
unsigned char    h : 4;
unsigned char    l : 4;
} BCD_REVERSE;
```

comments would be appreciated....